# Drawing Arrowhead curve with words (Objective-c cocos2D)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, curve, words, fractals

I'm trying to draw an arrowhead-curve using Fibonacci-esque words.  I may use method calls instead of building onto a string later on, but for now I want to preserve the string.

```
// create string. Initially set to "A"
NSMutableString *s1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[s1 setString:@"A"];

// loop through and replace A and B with the following strings. Toned down iterations to 5 here

for(int i=0; i<5; ++i){

    [s1 replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"A"
                  withString:@"+B-A-B+"
                      options:NSLiteralSearch
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, s1.length)];


    [s1 replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"B"
                          withString:@"-A+B+A-"
                  options:NSLiteralSearch
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, s1.length)];
}

// set line color, thickness
ccDrawColor4F(0.8, 1.0, 0.76, 1.0);
glLineWidth(1.0f);

float angle = 0;

float travelDist = 1; // distance in pixels the line is drawn. Can be changed to whatever

CGPoint p = CGPointMake(300,100);

for(int i = 0; i < [s1 length]; i++){

    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[s1 characterAtIndex:i]] isEqualToString:@"+"]){  // turn right

        angle += 60;

    }else if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[s1 characterAtIndex:i]] isEqualToString:@"-"]){ // turn left

        angle -= 60;

    }else{ // any other character, draw line

            float cosAngle = cosf(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle));

        float newDist = travelDist * cosAngle;

        float sinAngle = sinf(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle));

        float newDist2 = travelDist *sinAngle;

        ccDrawLine( ccp(p.x, p.y), ccp(p.x + newDist, p.y + newDist2) );

        p = CGPointMake(p.x + newDist, p.y + newDist2);

    }



}
```

I've read up on several sites about arrowhead curves, and the rules they must follow. It seems like I should be doing the right thing, but it doesn't turn out quite right. I get something representing a Sierpinski's triangle, but not a proper arrowhead curve.

[image]

You may not have to know Objective-c/Cocos2d to answer this, as I'm probably just doing something logistically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I need to create a new temporary string based on the current string, and go through one character at a time, and make the string the temporary one at the end of each iteration:

```
NSMutableString *s1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[s1 setString:@"A"];

NSMutableString *sTemp = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[sTemp setString:@""];


for(int i=0; i<6; ++i){

    for(int j = 0; j < [s1 length]; j++){


        unichar character = [s1 characterAtIndex:j];

        if(character == 'A'){

            [sTemp appendString:@"B-A-B"];

        }
        else if(character == 'B'){

            [sTemp appendString:@"A+B+A"];

        }else{

            [sTemp appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",character]];

        }

    }

    [s1 setString:sTemp];

    [sTemp setString:@""];

}
```